# How to bind a stage properties without listener?

Tags: binding, javafx

Is behavior like this a bug in javafx2 binding? 
It seems logical that standalone application itself is always self-informed about own state (xPosition, yPosition, height, width, and so on).
I'm reading book "Pro JavaFX 2 A Definitive Guide to Rich Clients with Java Technology" and some of code examples simply doesn't work. Note: The code I used here is mine. (Is this book relevant?)

```
package simplejavafxbindingquestion;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SceneBuilder;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBuilder;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.LabelBuilder;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBoxBuilder;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.PaneBuilder;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBoxBuilder;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextBuilder;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SimpleJavaFXBindingQuestion extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(final Stage stage) {

    Text textBoundStageHeight;
    Text textRequestedStageHeight;
    final Label labelRequestedStageHeight;
    VBox vBox;
    HBox hBox;
    Button btnRequest;
    Pane sceneRoot = PaneBuilder.create()
            .children(
              vBox = VBoxBuilder.create()
              .spacing(10)
              .children(
                textBoundStageHeight = TextBuilder.create()
                .textOrigin(VPos.TOP)
                .font(Font.font("Ariel", 20))
                .build(),
                hBox = HBoxBuilder.create()
                  .children(
                    textRequestedStageHeight = TextBuilder.create()
                      .textOrigin(VPos.TOP)
                      .font(Font.font("Ariel", 20))
                      .text("requested stage height: ")
                      .build(),
                    labelRequestedStageHeight = LabelBuilder.create()
                      .font(Font.font("Ariel", 20))
                      .text("Unknown")
                      .build()
                )
                .build(),
                btnRequest = ButtonBuilder.create()
                .text("Request height!")
                .font(Font.font("Ariel", 15))
                .onAction(new EventHandler<javafx.event.ActionEvent>() {
                  @Override
                  public void handle(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) {
                    labelRequestedStageHeight.setText("" + stage.getHeight());
                  }
                })
                .build()
              )
            .build()
            )
            .build();

    textBoundStageHeight.textProperty()
            .bind(new SimpleStringProperty("bound stage height: ")
            .concat(stage.getHeight()));

    Scene scene = SceneBuilder.create()
            .root(sceneRoot)
            .build();
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By saying "this behavior" I assume you are mentioning "stage.getHeight()" in

```
textBoundStageHeight.textProperty()
            .bind(new SimpleStringProperty("bound stage height: ")
            .concat(stage.getHeight()));
```

That behavior is not a bug, as documented in [concat](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/binding/StringExpression.html#concat%28java.lang.Object%29) javadoc:

> ... Also if the other Object is an implementation of ObservableValue,
>   changes in the other Object are reflected automatically in the
>   resulting StringExpression.

So since `stage.getHeight()` is not an `ObservableValue`, the changes of height value will not observed. On other hand `stage.heightProperty()` implements `ObservableValue`:

```
textBoundStageHeight.textProperty()
            .bind(new SimpleStringProperty("bound stage height: ")
            .concat(stage.heightProperty()));
```